# Number of solutions of a trigonometric equation.

Tags: trigonometry, diophantine-equations

The number of real solutions $x$ of the equation:

$\cos^2 (x\sin(2x))+ \dfrac {1}{1+x^2}=\cos^2x+\sec^2x$?

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** LHS $\le 2 \le$ RHS by AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Very nice :)${}{}$

Comment: How are you applying AM-GM inequality to the LHS?

Comment: You apply the AM-GM inequality to the RHS and not the LHS.